# Genius problems with iTunes and Match

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I have iTunes (10.6 40) and Match on my mac, as soon as I enabled match my "genius" playlists no longer work.

If I click genius on a track that is playing it says:

> Genius is unavailable for the song "Don't Drop It"

I click "Update Genius" and it says that the results have been updated, but never makes it available.

I have over 10K songs, so surely it can find a genius result for a G-Love or Jack Johnson song... but it never does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Click the iCloud download icon to download the song to the computer you're using, and then try again.

An edit: This has only worked sporadically for me.

Comment: Cool.  This seems to work... at least sporadically for me.  I'll keep an eye on it.  If it seems to work over 60% I'll mark this as the answer.